# Loading Umax Astra Slim 600 scanner on Ubuntu

Tags: scanner

Please help me with loading Umax Astra Slim 600 scanner on Ubuntu. I am unable to find a driver for Ubuntu and Linux.

Amit

Answer (score 0):

- You do not need a driver most of the times since Linux works with generic drivers.
- There is a package you might need though: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/sane-umax.5.html

  ```
   sudo apt-get install libsane-common
  ```

From the manual:

> NAME
>
> sane-umax - SANE backend for UMAX scanners
>
> ABOUT THIS FILE
>
> This  file only is a short descripton of the umax-backend for sane! For detailled information take a look at [sane-umax-doc.html](http://www.rauch-domain.de/sane-umax/index.html) (it is included in the sane source directory and in the xsane online help)!
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The  sane-umax library implements a SANE backend that provides acces to several  UMAX-SCSI-scanners  and  some  Linotye   Hell   SCSI-scanners, parallel-  and  USB-scanners  are  not  (and  propably  will  never be) supported! **I suggest you hold one hand on the power-button of  the  scanner  while you try the first scans!**

Comment: Please suggest what is to be done next? How should I load this ? I think as mentioned in the description USB scanners are not supported, I may never be able to use my scanner. Is there any possibility?

Comment: - did you have a look at the documentation I linked to? - What do you mean with "to be done next"? The package installs all you need (to be more precise: it installs `/usr/local/etc/sane.d/umax.conf` and sane picks this up)

Comment: Thanks for the help. please understand that for you it may be just a simple task but for a new user to ubuntu, its a mamoth to manage. Can you please suggest me a step by step process to install this package. I tried reading different information on installing the package, but frankly i was not able to do any thing. I am a windows user and life till date was very simple, just click a button and its all done.